# groupby with conditions and classify python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, classification, pandas-groupby

I have dataframe with 2 columns(name and id). There are thousands of names. But every name, there are only two ids(90 and 91, so in id column only contains 90 and 91).

**sample dataframe** is given below.

```
name    id
kevin   90
kevin   91
kevin   90
kevin   90
John    90
John    90
John    90
John    90
John    90
kevin   90
kevin   90
kevin   91
kevin   91
```

Firstly need to **groupby** using the name and id column and **get counts for each combination**.

Expected Output:

```
name    id  count
kevin   90  13
        91  2
elly    91  15
john    90  6
adam    90  3
        91  20
anjelo  90  12
        91  19
```

Then need to classify for violation using the following conditions.

1. A name contains **only one id**(90 or 91), it is **not a violation**(for example elly and john **are not** violators).
2. A name contains **both ids**,

   i.) **90**: less than 5 and  **91**: any number(greater than 0)   >>>>>>>   **Not a violator**(ex:adam)

   ii.) all the other id combinations>>>>>   **Violator** (ex:kevin and anjelo)

Finally expected Dataframe:

```
name    violation
kevin     1
elly      0
john      0
adam      0
anjelo    1
```

**What i have tried so for:**

Firstly i groupby using name and id and get counts for each combination(but this method does not return the above-shown dataframe.)

```
df.groupby(['name', 'id']).size().reset_index(name='counts')
```

In the second part, I only know how to identify violators if name  contain both ids(90 and 91). I don't know how to give the above-mentioned conditions to identified vioalators.

```
x = df.groupby('name').id.unique().reset_index()
x['Violation'] = x.id.apply(lambda x: 1 if (90, 91) in zip(x, x[1:]) else 0)
x.drop('id', 1, inplace=True)
x
```

really appreciate your support !!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's try [`crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) and boolean masking to locate violators:

```
# frequency table
s = pd.crosstab(df['name'], df['id'])

m1 = s.ne(0).sum(1).eq(1) # condition 1
m2 = ~m1 & s[90].lt(5) & s[91].gt(0) # condition 2
out = (~m1 & ~m2).view('i1').to_frame('violator') # violators
```

**Details:**

Calculate frequency table using [`crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html):

```
print(s)
        90  91
adam     3  20
anjelo  12  19
elly     0  15
john     6   0
kevin   13   2
```

Create boolean mask representing condition where *a name contains only one id(90 or 91)*:

```
print(m1)
name
adam      False
anjelo    False
elly       True # -> Non violator
john       True # -> Non violator
kevin     False
dtype: bool
```

Create boolean mask representing condition where *a name contains both ids,
and value for 90 is less than 5 while the value for 91 is greater than 0*:

```
print(m2)
name
adam       True # -> Non violator
anjelo    False
elly      False
john      False
kevin     False
dtype: bool
```

Combine `condition 1` and `condition 2` to get the violators:

```
print(out)
         violator
name             
adam            0
anjelo          1
elly            0
john            0
kevin           1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, mate. Learned a lot from your code.

Comment: @kevin Glad i could help.

Comment: very useful solution, but i have a question in crosstab function , how to remove the first row, I have a problem with when I classify the values the name of the column is appeared, I tried reset_index() but it convert the column name to a first column and it appeard like serial column, i hope u understand

Comment: to be more specific, how you remove the column name 'id' from the result and just keep the numbers 90 and 91

Answer (score 0):

After you've got the groupby counts, why don't you filter out the rows with ID=90 and count<5 and proceed with your logic? You can take a set of names before deleting and merge it with your final output in the end by filling nas in violations as 0.

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
g=df.groupby(['name','id']).size().to_frame('count').reset_index()#Groupby to get dataframe with count

#Allocate viloation
g['violation']=np.where((~g.name.duplicated(keep=False))|(g.id.eq(90)&g['count'].le(5)|g.id.eq(91)&g['count'].gt(0)),0,1)
print(g)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also try out to pivot the dataframe after your grouping step:

```
import pandas as pd    
pv=pd.pivot_table(df, values = 'counts', index=['name'], columns = 'id').reset_index().fillna(0)
pv.columns = pv.columns.map(str)
```

After that you can apply the logic in order to get your violation-flag:

```
import numpy as np
pv['violation'] = np.where((pv['90']==0) | (pv['91']==0) | (pv['90']<5) & (pv['91']>0),0,1)
```